# Web development : flash button submit form

Tags: html, flash, forms, button, submit

i have 2 textfields in html named : username and passwd, and i have a button in flash.
I want the flash button to submit the form and send the variables to my page welcome.php.

This is my code :

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="welcome.php" name=form2>
 <table>
 <div class="img2">
     <td><IMG SRC="acc2.png "></td>
   </div>
<div class="fieldHolder">

     <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textInput2"/></td>
 </div>

 <div class="fieldHolder3">

     <td><input type="password" name="passwd" class="textInput3"/></td>
     </div>

<div id="img2">

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 

codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/
cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 

width="75" height="29" 
 id="mymoviename"> 

<param name="movie"  

value="button16.swf" /> 

<param name="quality" value="high" /> 


<param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 

<embed src="button16.swf" quality="high" 

width="75px" height="28px" 

name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 

pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 


</embed> 

</object> 
</div>
</form>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start off by saying that you've thrown semantics right out the window with tables. Also, incorporating a flash button may significantly hinder the accessibility of the form.

I'm assuming you have the ability to edit the flash button you've created, but the question must be asked: Why can't you just style an `input` or `button` element?

As far as getting the form to submit: In flash you'll need to call some JavaScript using `ExternalInterface`.

```
function buttonClickListener(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  ExternalInterface.call('submitForm');
}
```

and in JavaScript you'll need to have a function named `submitForm` that submits the form.

## Don't do it; there are better ways.